# Working with shared files in .Net Core WebApps

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, filesystems

Let's say we have the following structure:

```
Solution:
 1. Project 1
 2. Project 2
```

And we want to share Resources between those projects, more specifically images.

If we use .NET Core 2.0 App

What are best practices ? Should we make a separate .NET Library where we store the images ? How to access files in such situation ?

If we have to stick to the principles of .NET Core, we should somehow expose a service which handles all workings with the files, am I correct?

Are there any existing solutions to this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Shared static resources should be handled via a virtual directory or some other distributed solution, such as a CDN.